# SQLite insert statement (using execSql) not functioning on Honeycomb or later

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using [execSql](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) to process an INSERT statement, and it has worked without error on all pre-Honeycomb versions of Android.  In Honeycomb and later, the application just hangs.  It does not return an Exception, or any kind of error.

The INSERT statement uses a compound SELECT statement with 3 UNION's to provide the values.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Edit: It seems it is only the final SELECT statement that causes the hang.

```
insert into RESULTS (Int_ID, SubjID, SubjName, SubjCompID,  SubjCompName, ObjID, ObjName, ObjCompID, ObjCompName,  IntType, MechID, Direction, Effect, Strength, Comment, Sort1, Sort2 )  
SELECT Int_ID, subdc.ID_comp as SubjID,  subdc.Name_comp as SubjName, ID_subject as SubjCompID,  subcompd.Name as SubjCompName, objdc.ID_Compound as ObjID,   objdc.Name_Compound as ObjName, ID_object as ObjCompID, objcompd.Name as ObjCompName,  IntType, MechID, Direction, Effect,Strength,Comment,   (subdc.ID_compound + objdc.ID_Compound)as Sort1, (ID_subject + ID_object)as Sort2  
FROM Int  
INNER JOIN t_Components subdc ON ID_subject = subdc.ID_Component  
INNER JOIN t_Components objdc ON ID_object = objdc.ID_Component  
INNER JOIN Comps subcompd ON ID_subject = subcompd.DrugID  
INNER JOIN Comps objcompd ON ID_object = objcompd.DrugID  
WHERE  subdc.ID_compound <> objdc.ID_Compound
```

Comment: It would help if you would actually provide the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add more statements to the WHERE clause; 
Maybe this post should be removed?

Comment: just tick yourself as the approved answer.. that will make it fade away from our sight..